# Apache Camel: all modifications of onRedelivery's processor is reset in next redelivery

Tags: apache-camel

All modifications of onRedelivery's processor is reset in next redelivery. Is there any way to make the modifications becomes permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are kept at each redelivery. You can use them to store information that you want to use after.

Code :

```
public class OnRedeliveryTest extends CamelTestSupport {

public static final String PROP_TEST = "PROP_TEST";
@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@Override
public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {

    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            onException(Exception.class)
                .onRedelivery(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        final String current = (String) exchange.getProperty(PROP_TEST);
                        exchange.setProperty(PROP_TEST, "property" + current);
                        System.out.println((String) exchange.getProperty(PROP_TEST));
                    }
                })
                .maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(0)
                .handled(true)
                .end();
            from("direct:start")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    }
                })
                .throwException(new Exception("BOOM"))
                .to("mock:end");
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void smokeTest() throws Exception {
    producerTemplate.sendBody("1");
}
```

}

In output, you will have :

propertynull

propertypropertynull

propertypropertypropertynull